# Git: Programmatically check if all submodules point to the correct commit

Tags: git, batch-file

In my build script I like to check if all submodules have the correct version checked out.

`git submodule status` gives me '+' or '-' but the exit-code is allways 0

I use a dos-batch file and I would like to have an error-code (%ERRORLEVEL%) 0 if all submodules point to the right commit or != 0 if at least one points to a different version.

Example output of git submodule status

```
$ git submodule status
 634e661fd09059a7337c930a9fc5489564dd4ba6 sub1 (heads/master)
+dceaedd21997d39ab043b0a3a02626fd38234aae sub2 (dceaedd)
 b1f1a58d912e0ab6a885e00cece601f1712d59a1 sub3 (heads/master)
```

sub2 has checked out an incorrect version denoted by '+'

From the documentation:

> Each SHA-1 will be prefixed with - if the submodule is not
>   initialized, + if the currently checked out submodule commit does not
>   match the SHA-1 found in the index of the containing repository and U
>   if the submodule has merge conflicts.

Comment: Fine. And what stops you from doing so? Would you mind to share your batch file and to tell us where you are stuck? By the way: it is *not* [DOS](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)!

Comment: As I never worked with git, I don't know what the output of `git submodule status` looks like. However, the task seems easy. Could you please post a sample output of the command?

Comment: @aschipfl: The error code is always 0 no matter if the version is ok or not

Comment: @MichaelS: At the momemt I use batch files but if I need to parse the output I would switch to python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
git submodule status | findstr "^-"
if %errorlevel%==1 exit /b 0
exit /b 1
```

`|findstr "^-"` will search the output for the minus sign (you have to escape it with `^`). If `-` is not present `findstr` will set errorlevel to 1. So we are doing `exit /b 0` which will invert the errorlevel to 0. Otherwise, `exit /b 1` is being executed and the errorlever will be set to 1.

Comment: Since I want to search for + at the start of the line I used this `git submodule status   | findstr /R "^+"` Works perfect